# Disabling specific context path in azure app insights

Tags: spring-boot, azure-application-insights

I have a `spring-boot` application that I have used alongside azure app insights and it works as expected.
Had a question on this: **Is it possible to exclude specific context paths?** I have just dropped in the starter and just configured the instrumentation key.

Are there any specific settings on `application.properties` that can fix this? Or do I need to create my own instance of `TelemetryClient`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you don't want to store some event in AI instance , If yes then you can use sampling feature to suppress some of the events.

You can set sampling in the Java SDK in the `ApplicationInsights.xml` file.

You can Include or Exclude specific types of telemetry from Sampling using the following tags inside the Processor tag "FixedRateSamplingTelemetryProcessor"

```
<ExcludedTypes>
        <ExcludedType>Request</ExcludedType>
    </ExcludedTypes>

    <IncludedTypes>
        <IncludedType>Exception</IncludedType>
    </IncludedTypes>
```

You can read more about sampling [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really sampling. I want all data for a set of API's that match a specific context root only. And it is in spring. This configuration is in .NET and it is not about sampling

Comment: Will check and vet back.